# WatchOS 2 - Perform a HTTP POST?

Tags: swift, nsurlsession, apple-watch

I know that WatchOS 2+ supports NSURLSession for some simple calls. I know that I can use the iOS companion app to performs POSTs for me and communicate it back - but can the watch perform those POST calls? I've tried and the operation has failed. Could be because of thread? Doesn't support POST?

```
let thisSpeakerIP = "192.168.1.170"
let url = NSURL(string:"http://\(thisSpeakerIP):8090/key")
let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringCacheData
let paramString = "<key state=\"press\" sender=\"Gabbo\">PRESET_4</key>"

request.HTTPBody = paramString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
    (let data, let response, let error) in
    guard let _:NSData = data, let _:NSURLResponse = response  where error == nil else {
        print("test watch error")
        return
    }
    let dataString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    print("dataString: '\(dataString!)'")

    let action = WKAlertAction(title: "OK", style: WKAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { () -> Void in
        //
    })

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        self.presentAlertControllerWithTitle("NSURLSession", message: "Got \(dataString!)", preferredStyle: WKAlertControllerStyle.SideBySideButtonsAlert, actions: [action])
    }
}
task.resume()
```

Comment: You might want to consider using a framework, such as [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire)

Comment: Alamofire is great but doesn't answer this particular question.

Comment: @RadagasttheBrown Have you got solution for this issue?